# Calling Uniswap V3 Quoter methods

Tags: uniswap

I tried to call `quoteExactInputSingle` and got the below error.

```
 contract.methods
  .quoteExactInputSingle(
    token0,
    token1,
    3000,
    "1000000000000000000000",
    0
  )
  .call()
  .then(console.log);
```

> Error: Returned error: execution reverted
> at Object.ErrorResponse (F:\work___Treasury\web3-caller\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\errors.js:28:19)
> at F:\work___Treasury\web3-caller\node_modules\web3-core-requestmanager\lib\index.js:300:36
> at F:\work___Treasury\web3-caller\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib\index.js:127:13
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
> data: null
> }

Answer (score 0):

You need only simulate the transaction, not execute. Try ethersjs with "quoterContract.callStatic.quoteExactInputSingle" or viemjs with "simulate". Look at the official example repository soo: https://github.com/Uniswap/examples/blob/main/v3-sdk/quoting/src/libs/quote.ts